# R get rid of string before/after special characters (pipe and <>) using regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to get rid of characters before or after special characters in a string.

My example string looks like this:

```
test <- c(">P01923|description", ">P19405orf|description2")
```

I'm trying to get the part between the `>` key and the `|` key, so that I'd be left with `c("P01923", "P19405orf")` only. I was trying to do this by using `gsub` twice, first to get rid of everything behind `|` and then to get rid of `>`.

I first tried this: `gsub("|.*, "", test)` but this seems to remove all the characters (not sure why?). I used the regex101.com website to check my regex and learned that `|` is a special character and that I need to use `\|` instead, and this worked in the regex101.com website, so I tried `gsub("\|.*", "", test)`, but this gave me an error saying `"\|' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\|"`. I'm having the same problem with `>`.

How can I get R to recognize special characters like `|` and `>` using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract text between `>` and `|`. Special characters can be escaped with `\\`.

```
sub('>(.*)\\|.*', '\\1', test)
#[1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because the regex website seemed to recognize `\` but I couldn't get it to work in R, I guess the website doesn't always use the same syntax with R.

Comment: Yes, usually regex websites use single slash \ to escape special characters whereas R uses two.

Comment: There is nothing really special about R here.  In a regex context, two backslashes denotes one single literal backslash.  Four backslashes can be used to represent an actual backslash character.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `"..."` to specify character constants you need also escape the `\` what leads to `\\`. But you can also use `r"(...)"` to specify *raw* character constants where you can use one `\`.

```
gsub(".*>|\\|.*", "", test)
[1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"

gsub(r"(.*>|\|.*)", "", test)
[1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"
```

Here `.*>` removes everything before and `>`, and `\|.*` removes `|` and everything after it and the `|` in between is an or.

Alternatively `regexpr` and `regmatches` could be used like:

```
regmatches(test, regexpr("(?<=>)[^|]*", test, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"
```

Where `(?<=>)` is a look behind for `>` and `[^|]*` matches everything but not `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex split option.  We can split the input string on `[>|]`, which will leave the desired substring in the second position of the output vector.

```r
test <- c(">P01923|description", ">P19405orf|description2")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(test, "[>|]"), function(x) x[2]))

[1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(stringr)

test <- c(">P01923|description", ">P19405orf|description2")

#if '>' is always the first character
str_sub(test, 2, -1) %>%
  str_replace('\\|.*$', '')
#> [1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"

#if not
str_replace(test, '\\>', '') %>%
  str_replace('\\|.*$', '')
#> [1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"

#alternative way 
str_match(test, '\\>(.*)\\|')[, 2]
#> [1] "P01923"    "P19405orf"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>